# emmeans in R - generating and interpreting contrasts

Tags: lme4-nlme, interpretation, poisson-regression, marginal-effect

I hope somebody is available to help a desperate rookie..

I fitted a glmer with a Poisson distribution and log link, including main effects and several interactions, an offset variable and a random effect. Something like this:

model1 <- glmer(count ~ A + B + C + A*B + offset(log(X)) + ( 1 | D),
data = workmap, family = poisson(link = "log"))

A, B and C are all factors with two levels.

My Prof generated "contrasts of marginal linear predictions" in Stata to, for example, look at the contrasts provided by A@B, or just simply A. I now want to do the same but in R by making use of the emmeans package.

- **First:** should I use emmeans() or contrast() command? What is the difference?

I did the following:
emm <- emmeans(model1, pairwise ~ A | B) #to generate contrasts
and
confint(emm, adjust = "none", level = 0.95) #to calculate confidence intervals

- **Second:** Can I calculate contrasts, CI and the p-value within one formula or do I have to do it separate like above?
- **Third:** Am I done or are there any additional steps I have to do before I can interpret the results?
- **Fourth:** I got the same p-values as my Prof but totally different "estimates" (he uses the IRR and I am not sure how "estimates" relate to the IRR), Confidence Intervals and my df says Inf whereas he gets proper values.

Please please help, it would be greatly appreciated.